# Linking multiple Data Extension attributes to a single Data Extension attributes

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, contactbuilder, data-designer

Ideally a contact has 2 Program Acronyms assigned, and these connect to another DE with full details about those Program Acronyms.

In other words - In Data Extension #1, a single contact has two fields: Program_Acronym_1 and Program_Acronym_2. In Data Extension #2, the primary key is a Program_Acronym field and there is other data about the Program in other fields.

How do I link the DEs so that both Program_Acronym_1 and Program_Acronym_2 from DE #1 connect to the Program_Acronym field in DE #2?

Thank you for any and all help, I know its a beginner question but I can't find the answer online. [image]

Comment: Thank you Niko for the suggestions! I'll create two separate DEs as you mentioned. I'm glad to get confirmation since I spent a bazillion hours trying to research this :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot connect one field from DE#1 to two other fields from DE#2 at the same time. What you can do though:

1. Split "Program_Acronym_1" and "Program_Acronym_2" fields into 2 separate Data Extensions, so that each DE will mirror another except for "Program_Acronym_1/2" fields. Once done connect both Data Extensions to the third one as you initially wanted but as separate relationships.
2. Analyse and create a totally new relationship based on the new fields between those two Data Extensions and connect them on it. It is recommended to create relationships using Primary Key.

In any case, some architectural data structure adjustments are required to achieve your goal.

Related source:

- [Data Designer in Contact Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_cab_data_designer.htm&type=5)
- [Contact Builder Best Practices](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_cab_contact_builder_best_practices.htm&type=5)